# Retrieve a particular row from database based on username or id

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

Hope some one can help me out here, 
i created a system with more than 1 user, each user have a unique username and id.
My problem now is how can i set my system in such a way that when a user log in, the system will direct the user to view a particular row in the database based on their username or id.

My Code to Access the Database is:

```
<?php


$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
mysql_select_db("uloaku", $con);
$count = 1;
$y = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM transaction WHERE username = '".$_SESSION['username']."' LIMIT 1");
if(mysql_num_rows($y) != 0){

echo "<table border=\"1\" width=\"800\" >";
echo "<tr id=\"bold\">
<td>No</td>
<td align=\"center\" width=\"120\">Account Owner</td>
<td align=\"center\" width=\"120\">Deposit Date</td>
<td align=\"center\" id=\"bold\" width=\"150\">Current Balance</td>
<td align=\"center\" width=\"150\">Available Balance</td>
<td align=\"center\">Account Status</td>
</tr>";

while ($z = mysql_fetch_array($y, MYSQL_BOTH)){
        echo "<tr>
        <td>".$count++."</td>
        <td id=\"color\" align=\"center\">".$z[1]."</td>
        <td id=\"color\" align=\"center\">".$z[2]."</td>
        <td id=\"color\" align=\"center\">".$z[3]."</td>
        <td id=\"color\" align=\"center\">".$z[4]."</td>
        <td id=\"color3\" align=\"left\">".$z[5]."</td>
        </tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";
    }
?>
```

My Login Page Looks Like This:

```
<?php

session_start();

$_SESSION['username'] = $username;

$username = $_POST['username'];

$password = $_POST['password'];

if ($username&&$password)

{
$connect = mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die("cannot connect!");
mysql_select_db("uloaku") or die("cannot find data base!");
$query = mysql_query ("SELECT * FROM keyaku WHERE    username='".mysql_real_escape_string($username)."' AND     password='".mysql_real_escape_string($password)."'");
$numrows = mysql_num_rows($query);

if ($numrows!=0)
{
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
{
    $dbusername = $row['username'];
    $dbpassword = $row['password'];
}
if ($username==$dbusername&&$password=$dbpassword)
{
    echo "Welcome $username";
}
else
    echo "Invalid Password";
}
else
die("Invalid User");

}

else
 die("Please Enter a UserName and Password.");

?>
```

So far my log-in is working as i want it, and my database retrieves information the only problems is that it retrieves all information which is in the database but i want it to retrieve information based on the username or id of the person that logs in

Comment: Read up about [HEREDOC](http://php.net/heredoc) and stop using those ugly multi-line-plus-escapes echo statements. Your code maintainers will thank you for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I bet this piece of code does not work at all:

```
$query = mysql_query ("SELECT * FROM keyaku WHERE        username='$username'&&password='$password'");
```

... there is no such thing as && in MySQL, therefore the query will return empty result. If you want it to work, do it at least this way (prevents [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection), too!):

```
$query = mysql_query ("SELECT * FROM keyaku WHERE username='".mysql_real_escape_string($username)."' AND password='".mysql_real_escape_string($password)."'");
```

Second of all, you need some way to store your login information, so it can be reused later on. If you can use sessions, the simplest way is to store username (or whichever information is linked to the row you need):

```
$_SESSION['username'] = $username;
```

Then, in your first page, update SQL to read as follows (change the column ID per your needs):

```
$y = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM transaction WHERE username = '".$_SESSION['username']."' LIMIT 1");
```

... you don't even need the `LIMIT 1` part if your username field in transaction table is indexed as a primary/unique key.

Comment: Hi Zathrus, thanks for the reply, i have modify my first page to access the data base as follows. refer to my code above. and am still getting an error which says: Notice: Undefined variable: username in C:\wamp\www\ct001\viewacct.php on line 82, line 82 is the part i added $_SESSION['username'] = $username; assist me i guess am doing something wrong  here. thanks

Comment: the `$_SESSION['username'] = $username;` line belongs to your login page - it stores the username of the logged-in person, so you can retrieve that one database row for them

Comment: Hi Zathrus, Am still getting the same error, do you mind to help edit the codes from my question so i can take corrections from there. or if there is any other better way you suggest i re-write my codes, just state it up am open for changes. thanks

Comment: you need to follow what PHP is telling you - it tells you that $username is undefined and it is true - you are trying to assign $username **above** the line where you're actually creating it... in other words, $username is being set on line 7 but you're trying to use it on line 5 already